# Javascript call parent function from child after window.opener.location.reload

Tags: javascript, window.opener

I have two pages. The parent page opens a popup with javascript. 
From the child page(popup), i reload the parent page. After that I would like to invoke a method called `doSomething()`.

Parent page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
             function doSomething(){
                 // code ...
             }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        // open child page
    </body>
</html>
```

Child page:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            window.opener.location.reload(true);
            window.opener.doSomething();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But javascript invokes the `doSomething()` first and only after that performes `window.opener.location.reload()`.

Is there a way to know on child page when `window.opener.location.reload(true)` has completed before calling the second method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about your are using it like this:

```
window.opener.location.reload(true);
if(document.readyState === "complete") {
    window.opener.doSomething();
}
```

Because your are using the whole document you could check if its already loaded or not.